# Azure API - how to find out if a VM is running or deallocated

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-rest-api, azure-vm

I am trying to generate a report of usage on a calendar and the missing metric is running/stop VS deallocated time.

Looking at the API documentation there does not seems to be a straight forward way to get this information from neither the vm api or the cost management.

Any suggestions on how to get this metric?

Answer (score 2):

**Powershell**.  Look for the PowerState status.

```
Get-AzVM -Status
```

**C#**

```
ResourceId vmResourceId = ResourceId.FromString(vmResourceId);
var authenticated = Azure.Configure().Authenticate(Common.Credentials);
vmInner = await authenticated.WithSubscription(vmResourceId.SubscriptionId).VirtualMachines.Inner.GetAsync(vmResourceId.ResourceGroupName, vmResourceId.Name, InstanceViewTypes.InstanceView);
PowerState = vmInner.InstanceView.Statuses.Where(i => i.Code.Contains("PowerState")).FirstOrDefault()?.DisplayStatus;
```

**API** - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/instanceview.  Look for the statuses array where code = "PowerState/running".

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}/instanceView?api-version=2019-07-01
```

Comment: One more helpful hint.  If you know how to do something in Powershell, just add the -Debug switch (or set $debugpreference='continue') and you will see the underlying REST API.